# Rank of matrix n x m

Tags: matrices

What is the most efficient way to calculate the rank of matrix A with dimmension n x m?
I am intrested if it's rank is highest possible -> rank(A) = n

Thank you in advance

Comment: Not really a research question (despite the upvotes), given that much information is easily available online. The first result returned by a Google search for "fast rank matrix" is https://arxiv.org/abs/1203.6705. Another one is http://www-scf.usc.edu/~hoyeeche/papers/matrix-rank.pdf.

Comment: This is not a research question for MO; I think it should be migrated to M.SE or elsewhere; to others who click 'close' please help migrate this to the right forum, rather than just abstractly close!

Comment: Of course, asking for the most efficient way of computing the rank of a real matrix is like asking for the most efficient way of cutting your own throat/

Answer (score 2):

[Fast Matrix Rank Algorithms and Applications](http://www-scf.usc.edu/~hoyeeche/papers/matrix-rank.pdf) (2013)

> We consider the problem of computing the rank $r$ of an $n \times m$
>   matrix $A$ over a field. Our randomized algorithm requires $O(mn)$ operations, which for $n<m$ is faster than the 
>   conventional algorithm based on Gaussian elimination.

See also this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34057499/what-is-the-fastest-way-library-to-calculate-the-rank-of-a-matrix-in-c) posting.